# GWT popupPanel:Child element do not aware of visibility of parent element

Tags: gwt, popuppanel

There is the main panel in that panel there are different fields like text box cell, integer box cell which contains popup panel.Popup panel is instantiated from the text box or integer box.So when popup panel is fired from the cell, application makes server call it may take some time to populate that popup panel.Meanwhile if user close the parent panel, popup panel doesn't know where to place itself as while it showed up the parent panel and the cell box from where it instantiated is already gone. So it places itself to the default location that is at top left corner of the screen.So how this case should be handled?How pop panel will come to know that its grandparent element is hidden and it should not display itself anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user clicks on a box, start a server call. In `onSuccess()` method of a callback, check if the popup is still needed. If yes, show it.